# Use of "deadpool" as a verb

Tags: meaning, verbs, slang, business-language

I recently came across this term while examining a set of properties in a JSON feed relating to a startup company:

```
 ...
 "deadpooled_year": null,
 "deadpooled_month": null,
 "deadpooled_day": null,
 "deadpooled_url": null,
 ...
```

I searched for the word, and find several non-authoritative sources (e.g., *The Urban Dictionary*), but nothing definitive. I gather it means something like "defunct" or "obsoleted" — handed over to the pool of dead companies which have been surpassed and made irrelevant by other, more successful companies. I also infer that it is a fairly well known term used in the startup lexicon. Yet this is the first time I've encountered it.

Can anyone shed some light on the term "deadpool" or "deadpooled"? A citation from a serious publication that uses the term in a way that makes the meaning obvious and unmistakeable? Please, no speculation. I have already speculated enough about this.

Comment: Setting aside the place I found it, it seems to mean something apart from what a programmer chose to call something. So I disagree that it's too localized. There are attributions, as I say, in non-authoritative sources; I'm asking for a proper attribution.

Comment: Obviously those who voted to close haven't an interest in changing language, and could not get past the way I discovered this word, nor that has much wider application than you allow.

Comment: "Dot-Com Deadpool" was already in use in [June, 2000](http://www.salon.com/2000/06/06/deadpool/).

Comment: @ΜετάEd: That Salon.com article uses "Dot-com deathwatch" but their subject Fuckedcompany.com used the dot-com deadpool as their tagline  in at least [August 2000](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20000815000000*/http://www.fuckedcompany.com/), and probably a bit earlier. This probably started the IT use, and I expect generated a verb somewhere, but I've only found nouns there.

Comment: @Hugo The Salon article is older than the Wayback Machine's archive. The article, dated 6 June 2000, already describes Fuckedcompany.com as a "riff off the Celebrity Dead Pool Web site". That dates Fuckedcompany.com's use of the tagline to before 6 June 2000.

Comment: The phrase "dead pool" (referring to the death of individuals, usually celebrities or athletes) goes back to at least the 50's and was used as a movie title (for the last *Dirty Harry* sequel) in 1988.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Deadpool*, *deadpooled* and *deadpooling* have been used hundreds of time by the popular blog [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/search/deadpooled). They tag with [DEADPOOL](http://techcrunch.com/tag/deadpool/) posts about companies and startups that have folded, or other things considered deprecated. The related CrunchBase has the [deadpooled](http://www.crunchbase.com/companies?q=deadpooled) category for companies.

Some citations:

- [2007](http://techcrunch.com/2007/10/28/imthere-joins-madeit-as-the-most-recent-attempts-to-crack-the-event-nut/): "None of the recent startups (renkoo, socializr, mypunchbowl and the **deadpooled** Skobee) have presented much of a challenge."
- [2008](http://techcrunch.com/2008/03/12/snaptalent-targets-job-candidates-where-they-work-and-spend-time-online/): "The founders of Snaptalent say there’s nothing else available that competes directly with their offering (although **deadpooled** Edgeio came the closest)."
- [2008](http://techcrunch.com/2008/03/27/techcrunch-deadpooled-my-company-and-all-i-got-was-this-lousy-ipod-shuffle/): "TechCrunch **DeadPooled** My Company And All I Got Was This Lousy iPod Shuffle"
- [2009](http://techcrunch.com/2009/04/03/deliveryedge-tumbles-into-the-deadpool/): "DeliveryEdge Tumbles Into The **Deadpool** ... We predicted that the company might suffer the same fate as Kozmo, which burned through $280 million in capital before it was **deadpooled** in 2001."
- [2009](http://I%E2%80%99m%20deadpooling%20this%20.ECO%20top%20level%20domain%20right%20now.%20Not%20because%20it%E2%80%99s%20global%20warming/eco%20related,%20there%E2%80%99s%20plenty%20of%20money%20being%20thrown%20around%20to%20support%20just%20about%20every%20crazy%20green%20idea%20out%20there.%20I%20just%20don%E2%80%99t%20think%20the%20world%20needs%20another%20top%20level%20domain): "I’m **deadpooling** this .ECO top level domain right now. Not because it’s global warming/eco related, there’s plenty of money being thrown around to support just about every crazy green idea out there. I just don’t think the world needs another top level domain"
- [2010](http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/30/chango/): "Sukornyk is a serial entrepreneur with a mixed track record. Previously he co-founded the X-Stream Network (a free ISP in Europe sold to LibertySurf for $75 million), Bubbleshare (photo-sharing site sold to Kaboose for a couple million dollars, and then **deadpooled**), and FiveLimes (a green shopping site sold to Avid Life Media, which now appears to be defunct)."
- [2011](http://www.crunchbase.com/company/judysbook): "Judy’s Book was founded in early 2004. Competitors include Yelp, insiderpages, Craigslist and Citysearch. The company was **deadpooled** in October 2007. In October 2008 Judy’s book relaunched with new owners."

TechCrunch first used it as a noun in "the TechCrunch DeadPool" in [2006](http://techcrunch.com/2006/06/03/foldcomfolds/):

> Well, the inevitable is starting to happen - a few new web startups are starting to close up shop as they find that building an application is a lot easier than getting users to try it out, and keep coming back. Fold.com, an Ajax home page, has folded. [...]
>
> In anticipation of the inevitable thinning of new web startups, I’ve added the tag “**DEADPOOL**” to our Company & Product Index. Hopefully we won’t be using that tag too often in the near future.

Their earliest verb use I found is from [2007](http://techcrunch.com/2007/07/22/time-to-deadpool-tailrank-you-decide/):

> Time To **DeadPool** TailRank? You Decide. [...]
>
> Should TailRank Be **DeadPool’d**?
>
> - Viagra? **DeadPool** It

Comment: Against all the odds, you seem to have nailed the actual "coinage" for the database fields, by Michael Arrington in that TechCrunch 2006 link. I don't much rate the question, but I feel I must upvote this answer for sheer diligence! :)

Comment: Seems they've extended the concept of a celebrity death pool, to a corporate death pool.

Answer (score 1):

Google tells me that Deadpool is a Marvel Comics character.

Prior to that, a "Dead Pool" refers to a somewhat macabre game, in which people bet on which celebrities will die first, and taking its name from a conventional betting pool.

In the programming context you cite, it's likely that the coder has taken the words, and applied them to a pool of resources that have served their useful purpose.

There doesn't seem to be any precedent for using it as a verb, although "pool" can of course be used as a noun. In informal use, of course, it's quite common to verb nouns. "Verbing nouns funnies English".

Comment: You're thinking of a *death* pool (more specifically, a celebrity death pool).

Comment: For the programming comment, the JSON snippet in the question looks like what is in some CrunchBase JSON output so it's probably related to TechCrunch/CrunchBase like mentioned in http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51945/32044